# Laravel - controller/view to return xml or json

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5.4 and I've a GenerateController with a route. Route::get('/generate', 'GenerateController@index');

Then in the index function it will read request parameter format = xml or csv or json.

So is there a way when I return view() inside the controller I can return different format and I guess the response header need to pass back rather it's xml, csv or json?

Comment: You can check laravel-formatter package and how it works.

Comment: Hi Did you actually use it? Just wondering cuz I see the following and it returns in different format. I think I can use it or at least to json format I can just pass the data array and use json_encode instead. I was more asking if there's a way for the view or laravel built in function that will actually return it along with response header. Sorry I'm not specific enough. Cuz you will need to set those content type = text/csv, etc.? It seems the view will always return response header text/html?

$csv   = $formatter->toCsv();
$json  = $formatter->toJson();
$xml   = $formatter->toXml();

Comment: Just figured it out beside the formatter instead of return view then do return response along with header. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses